# Ember + Handlebars render Rails validation errors as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, handlebars.js

Given this json response:

```
{"username":null,"errors":{"password":["is required"],"username":["is required","is too short","is invalid"],"email":["is required","is invalid"]}}
```

I want to render the first error message of each attribute.
Ember picks up the errors correctly, and I am able to parse them in an Handlebars template, like:

```
<div {{bind-attr class='errors.email:error'}}>
  <label>Email Address</label>
  {{view Ember.TextField type='email' valueBinding='model.email' placeholder='Email Address'}}
  <small class='below'>{{errors.email}}</small>
</div>
```

But `{{errors.email}}` renders `[object Object]` or a multitude of these. Adding `.[0]`, or `firstObject` reduces this to only render `[object Object]` once, but it is not parsing the correct error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the ActiveModelAdapter, error messages get automatically paired to attribute / message. As @kingpin2k explained in his gist, `errors.email.firstObject` will get the first object, from which you'll need the message attribute.

I created this helper, to dry it up a bit:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('error', function(context) {
    if(context && context.length)
        return context[0].message;
});
```

Use it like this in your hbs templates:

```
{{error errors.email}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edo, this looks like it's working properly.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OZaNAYuc/1/edit